# How to set limit on Aeron subscriber and publisher count while Running Aeron Samples

Tags: java, testing, gradle, limit, aeron

I'm running the Aeron samples as given [here](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron#running-samples).

Steps to run the test:

```
git clone --branch 1.27.0 https://github.com/real-logic/aeron.git
gradle --console='plain' --stacktrace assemble
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /src/aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.27.0.jar -Daeron.dir=/dev/shm/aeron-root io.aeron.driver.MediaDriver &
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /src/aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.27.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicSubscriber &
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /src/aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.27.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicPublisher &
```

Output of test

```
Offering 53747/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3439776) <<Hello World! 53747>>
Offering 53748/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3439840) <<Hello World! 53748>>
Offering 53749/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3439904) <<Hello World! 53749>>
Offering 53750/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3439968) <<Hello World! 53750>>
Offering 53751/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3440032) <<Hello World! 53751>>
Offering 53752/10000000 - yay!
Message to stream 1001 from session -1579104823 (18@3440096) <<Hello World! 53752>>
```

As shown in the output, there are 1000000 Subscribe and Publish events that are going to take place.

#### So my question is how can I limit the number of interactions. Doing so using some flags would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the number of messages send by the BasicPublisher using the `aeron.sample.messages` system property as follows:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp /src/aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.27.0.jar -Daeron.sample.messages=100 io.aeron.samples.BasicPublisher &
```